# Why is Hibernate selecting same columns 4 times? Help with Mapping?

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

My classes look like these. Why does the same column get selected 4 times? What is problem with the mapping?

```
@Entity @Table(name="CLIENTS")
public class Client implements Serializable {

  @Id @GeneratedValue   @Column(name="GENERATED_ID")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name="NAME")
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="client", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  private Map<ParamPK, Param> params = new HashMap<ParamPK, Param>();
}

@Entity @Table(name="PARAMS")
public class Param implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId
  private ParamPK paramPK;

  @Column(name="VALUE")
  private String value;

  @ManyToOne @MapsId("clientId")
  private Client client;
}

@Embeddable
public class ParamPK implements Serializable {

  @Column(name="PARAM_KEY")
  private String key;

  @Column(name="CLIENT_GENERATED_ID")
  private Long clientId;
}
```

The queries generated by select gets same column 4 times.

```
/* from Client */ 
select
    client0_.GENERATED_ID as GENERATED1_1_,
    client0_.NAME as NAME1_ 
from
    CLIENTS client0_

/* load one-to-many Client.params */ 
select
    params0_.client_GENERATED_ID as client3_1_1_,
    params0_.client_GENERATED_ID as client3_1_,
    params0_.PARAM_KEY as PARAM1_1_,
    params0_.CLIENT_GENERATED_ID as CLIENT3_1_,
    params0_.client_GENERATED_ID as client3_0_0_,
    params0_.PARAM_KEY as PARAM1_0_0_,
    params0_.VALUE as VALUE0_0_ 
from
    PARAMS params0_ 
where
    params0_.client_GENERATED_ID=?
```

Note using Hibernate 3.5.3. Rest boilerplate code has been removed as irrelevant.

Comment: Could you show the JPQL query?

Comment: Not sure it will help, but have you tried adding a MapKey(name = "paramPK") annotation on your Map<ParamPK, Param>?

Comment: @Psy the query is plain `em.createQuery("from Client");`

Comment: @JB your solution has now changed the column names in select query so no more duplicates. That solves my issue. Please post your response as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to tell Hibernate what constitutes the key of the map of parameters. Add the following annotation to this map:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="client", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@MapKey(name = "paramPK")
private Map<ParamPK, Param> params = new HashMap<ParamPK, Param>();
```

This tells Hibernate that the paramPK property of the Param entity is the key of the map.